# Connect to remote Sqlserver using arcobject

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, sql-server

I want to connect to a database assigned to a vps with an IP address. I used this string to connect to Database when it was on localhost. How I change it to connect to remote one?

```
IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySetClass();
propertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "sde:sqlserver:CRAZYVIRUS-HP");
propertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", "land_gis");
propertySet.SetProperty("USER", "LandManagment");
propertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", "pass");
//propertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", "dbo.DEFAULT");
//propertySet.SetProperty("authentication_mode", "OSA");

workspace = workspaceFactory2.Open(propertySet, 0);
```

I use ArcObjects 10.2.1 version and C#

Comment: This isn't a GIS question; you would likely have a more knowledgeable audience on a Microsoft SQL-Server forumn. If the neworking tools of the database can't connect,  there's zero chance a third-party application can.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have an example of how I connect to an SDE database. I normally left  Server and Database as empty parameters.

```
    Guid sdebGUID = new Guid("D9B4FA40-D6D9-11D1-AA81-00C04FA33A15");
    Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(sdebGUID);
    IWorkspaceFactory wsF = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType) as IWorkspaceFactory;

    IPropertySet pSet = new PropertySetClass();
    pSet.SetProperty("Server", "");
    //name of server
    pSet.SetProperty("Instance", "sde:sqlserver:CRAZYVIRUS-HP");
    //port
    pSet.SetProperty("Database", "");
    //name of Database
    pSet.SetProperty("User", "your user");
    //name of user connecting to DB
    pSet.SetProperty("Password", "your password");
    //password
    pSet.SetProperty("Version", "SDE.DEFAULT"); // This is the version I use

    //version to be connected
    IWorkspace ws = wsF.Open(pSet, pApplication.hWnd); //pApplication is of the type IApplication
    IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as IFeatureWorkspace;

    //example of a connection to a feature class
    IFeatureClass featureClassOut = fws.OpenFeatureClass("ADMSDE.MUNICIPALITIES");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a "Server" property which should set through propertyset interface.And if so,isn't it enough to change server name and SQLServer instance name to the name of remote database server and SQL instance which is running on it?for example :

```
    IPropertySet ipPropSet = new PropertySetClass();
    ipPropSet.SetProperty("SERVER", "RemoteServer123");
    ipPropSet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "SDE:SQLServer:RemoteServer123");
    ipPropSet.SetProperty("DATABASE", "GeoDB1");
    ipPropSet.SetProperty("USER", "sa");
    ipPropSet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", "pass");
    ipPropSet.SetProperty("VERSION", "dbo.Default");
```

Comment: Dear Reza,I have searched and I found that server must be in this form"sde:sqlserver:CRAZYVIRUS-HP" and CRAZYVIRUS-HP is instance name of sql server.But Idont know how to address instance of sqlserver on remote server.should it be as ip/CRAZYVIRUS-HP or something like that?

Comment: yes you can use this format for SQLServer instance name for example "HPServerName\SQLServerInstance"

Comment: No, the SERVER component is not used at all in Direct Connect connections. The INSTANCE parameter specfies the RDBMS hostname used in Microsoft's connection protocol.

Comment: @Vince So if I use it as a normal ip address like what I use in connection strings it works?